# explain how to use this specific function of foldl

Tags: haskell

```
 sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a  
 sum xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs
```

foldl is folds the list up from the left side. So first we get the `acc=0` and put the list xs to x ,then doing the function `->acc+x`.After calculation, we get the new acc which is equal to `acc+x`. But why is that? I think this result of `acc+x` is the new value of x based on the function `x->acc+x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at your definition of sum

```
sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a  
sum xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs
```

Let's also take a peek at foldl's signature:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

Hmm, ok, what do we have to feed foldl in order to get the value at the very, very end (`->a`)?

1. It needs a curried function `(a->b->a)`. All though not accurate, for brevity's sake, we'll say its a function that takes two arguments (but you and I know that really, it takes one argument and returns another function that takes one argument).
2. It needs a value of type `a`. Notice that our curried function from Step 1. takes something of type `a` and returns something of type `a`. Interesting...hmmm...
3. It needs a list of type `b`. Notice our curried function from Step 1 takes, as well as something of type `a`, something of type `b`.

So, do we give it what it wants?

1. We give it `(\acc x -> acc + x)`. This is an **anonymous** function, or **lambda**, that takes two arguments, (remember, it's curried, though), `acc` and `x`, and return's their sum.
2. We give it `0` as our starting value
3. We give it `xs` as the list to fold.

Ok dokie. So, let's just let foldl work its Haskell magic. Let's imagine we called `sum [1,2,3]`

`foldl` calls our function `(\acc x -> acc + x)`, using `0` for `acc` and the first value of `xs`, `1`.

```
 0 + 1
```

This result does **not** get stored away in `acc` or `x`, since they are just arguments in our little lambda function. `foldl` is going to use that value (see [SanSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761367/explain-how-to-use-this-specific-function-of-foldl/4761501#4761501)'s answer for the specific implementation).

Remember that the result of our lambda function is the same type as the first parameter? foldl can use that previous sum and pass it back to the lambda function, along with the **second** element.

```
(0 + 1) + 2
```

And again until it has done this for all the elements:

```
((0 + 1) + 2) + 3
6
```

As pointed out by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761367/explain-how-to-use-this-specific-function-of-foldl/4763090#4763090), this is the same if you had done:

```
sum xs = foldl (+) 0 xs
```

You can tell more easily with this function that we aren't just 'setting' some variable and adding onto it.

Hope this helps.

---

Side note: 
For your definition of sum, you don't have to explicitly state that `sum` takes `xs`. You could leave it as:

`sum = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0`

This takes advantage of currying, because if we provide foldl just its first two arguments -- a curried function like `(a->b->a)` and a value of type `a` -- what do we get?

`[b] -> a`

A function that takes a list of type `b` and returns a value of type `a`! This is called [pointfree style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree). Just something to consider :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the definition of foldl:

```
foldl  f z []     =  z
foldl  f z (x:xs) =  foldl f (f z x) xs
```

foldl recieves a funcion which takes 2 arguments, a value (the "starter value" or accumulator) and a list.
In case the list is empty it returns the current calculation.
If the case is not empty then it calls recursively with the same function as function,  the accumulator is the result of the invocation of the function using the accumulator as the first argument and the first element of the list as the second argument and the tail of the list is used as the list for the recursive call.

So the lambda function used in sum becomes quite clear it takes acc as first argument and the element of the list as second argument and return the sum of both.

The result of the invocations for:

```
sum [1,2,3] = ((0 + 1) + 2) + 3 = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it sounds like you don't understand how the lambda function `(\acc x -> acc + x)` works here.

The function is not `x->acc+x`, but `acc x->acc + x`. In fact, you could rewrite the "sum" equation as

```
sum xs = foldl (+) 0 xs
```

Since `(\acc x -> acc + x)` is the same as `(+)`

I suggest you (re)read http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#lambdas